# Insert multiple columns to another table based on 1 distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Below is the structure of my table diary, which has some entries about trips. The problem is there are around 4,000  duplicate entries which I found after hashing the notes column into hash column. Total entries are around 47,000.

[image: Table structure]

**I want to delete all the duplicate rows leaving just 1 row based on the `hash` column**

I can find the duplicate rows using

```
SELECT `url`, COUNT(hash) c from diary GROUP BY `hash` HAVING c > 1 ORDER BY `c` DESC;
```

and then use this SQL to find the url id of the duplicate rows

```
SELECT `url`, places, days,`hash` FROM  diary WHERE `hash` = (select `hash` from diary WHERE `url` = ?);
```

[image: Desired output]

For this table I want to have any 1 row from the first 2 rows as they have same hash and 3rd, 4th row. Also to be noted in the diary table there may be duplicate `hash` with count as high as 400.

Ans:
Add hash as unique key then
**INSERT IGNORE INTO diary2 (c1, c2, c3) SELECT cl, c2 FROM diary;**

Comment: Please add sample data which helps to explain what a "duplicate" is.

Comment: The question body doesn't seem to agree with the title

Comment: Can an URL have more than one different hash value?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you mean by "duplicates" exactly, but to answer the last part of your question:

For this table I want to have any 1 row from the first 2 rows as they have same hash and 3rd, 4th row. Also to be noted in the diary table there may be duplicate `hash` with count as high as 400.

you can use the row_number function for this:

```
with cte as (
select `url`, places, days,`hash`, 
rownumber() over (partition by hash) rown 
from diary where `hash` = (select `hash` from diary WHERE `url` = ?)
)
select * from cte where rown = 1;
```

Partitioning by `hash`, means that the rown column will have 1 as value for the first line with `hash=1` and 2 as value for the second line. And by specifying that you want to select rows with `rown=1`, you will get the first line for `hash=1` (and the single line for `hash=3` and `hash=4`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example to delete a duplicate row.

**Sample Table Data :**

```
   url    days  places  itenerary    flag  remarks    hash  
------  ------  ------  ---------  ------  -------  --------
     1       1       1          1       0   (NULL)         1
     2       2       2          2       0   (NULL)         1
     3       3       3          3       0   (NULL)         3
     4       4       4          4       0   (NULL)         4
     5       5       5          5       0   (NULL)         4
```

### DELETE QUERY

Delete duplicate using this query according to duplicate `hash`:

```
DELETE t1 FROM diary t1 INNER JOIN diary t2
WHERE t1.`url`>t2.`url` AND `t1`.`hash`=`t2`.`hash`;
```

**Result :**

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings
Query: delete t1 from diary t1 inner join diary t2 where t1.`url`>t2.`url` and `t1`.`hash`=`t2`.`hash`
2 row(s) affected

   url    days  places  itenerary    flag  remarks    hash  
------  ------  ------  ---------  ------  -------  --------
     1       1       1          1       0   (NULL)         1
     3       3       3          3       0   (NULL)         3
     4       4       4          4       0   (NULL)         4
```

This will delete any duplicates and leave 1 copy with the lowest url number per duplicate.

Link:
**[How To Delete Duplicate Rows in MySQL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/)**